# python pandas dataframe merge or join dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I want to help yours

if i have a pandas dataframe merge

first dataframe is

```
D = { Year, Age, Location, column1, column2... }
      2013, 20 , america, ..., ...
      2013, 35, usa, ..., ...
      2011, 32, asia, ..., ...
      2008, 45, japan, ..., ...
```

shape is 38654rows x 14 columns

second dataframe is

```
D = { Year, Location, column1, column2... }
      2008, usa, ..., ...
      2008, usa, ..., ...
      2009, asia, ..., ...
      2009, asia, ..., ...
      2010, japna, ..., ...
```

shape is 96rows x 7 columns

I want to merge or join two different dataframe.
How can I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with parameter `how='left'` if need left join on column `Year` and `Location`:

```
print (df1)
   Year  Age Location  column1  column2
0  2013   20  america        7        5
1  2008   35      usa        8        1
2  2011   32     asia        9        3
3  2008   45    japan        7        1

print (df2)
   Year Location  column1  column2
0  2008      usa        8        9
1  2008      usa        7        2
2  2009     asia        8        2
3  2009     asia        0        1
4  2010    japna        9        3

df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['Year','Location'], how='left')
print (df)
   Year  Age Location  column1_x  column2_x  column1_y  column2_y
0  2013   20  america          7          5        NaN        NaN
1  2008   35      usa          8          1        8.0        9.0
2  2008   35      usa          8          1        7.0        2.0
3  2011   32     asia          9          3        NaN        NaN
4  2008   45    japan          7          1        NaN        NaN
```

You can also check [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

Comment: not print dataframe...

Comment: only viewing columns

Comment: why can i see the nan data.. :(

Comment: That's good dataframe merge I think, but.. I can't see it..

Comment: You see `nan` data where column are not match - e.g. in my sample in `df2` are not `2013` with `20` data.

Comment: hm.. question's failed. I think...

Comment: If... only Yearly is just 1 data, but another dataframe have a lots of data that Years. it just extent to it?

Comment: Why do you think?

Comment: sorry extent -> extend.

Comment: Hmmm, i am not sure if I understand you. Maybe help check nice pictures in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra) - do you need left, inner or outer join? What column are joined on? What is desired output from input?

Comment: well.. i want to this. year, age, location, column1, column2... but.. I using it docs that join, merge, etc.. but I can't.. :(

Comment: If when I using it left and right merge, just view to dataframe1, not viewing dataframe2..

Comment: with your real data?

Comment: yes. it's real data.. first dataframe using sas preprocessing, another dataframe is read mysql data.

Comment: I have a idea - what is `df1.info()` and `df2.info()` ?

Comment: class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 38654 entries, 0 to 38653
Data columns (total 14 columns):

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 96 entries, 0 to 95
Data columns (total 7 columns):

Comment: first dataframe type is here dtypes: category(1), float64(12), object(1), another dataframe type is here dtypes: float64(5), object(2)

Comment: hmm, formating is not nice. But I think you can check `dtypes` of matching columns - what is `df1.dtypes` and `df2.dtypes`?

Comment: dtypes comment is 14,15 comments. thank's alot jezrael

Comment: Now it working?

Comment: not this working .. :( how can i using it one to many data handling?

Comment: I think there is problem `dtypes` of matching columns are different - e.g. in `df1` it is `object` and in `df2` it is `int`.

Comment: hm... ok... do that...